# How do I properly nest in SVN

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I have a django project let's call `Project`
There is a repository at the top level of the django project.

```
Project
   Project
   App
   Common
```

When I check out Common into Project, it breaks all the shell overlay icons in windows explorer, suggesting that this isn't the right way. I googled a bit but only came across some SO questions that weren't related..

How should I do this?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should add the `Common`-repository as svn:external.

**HOWTO: Add svn:externals in windows using tortoisesvn**:

1. Go to the root of the folder you want to add the externals to.
2. Right click on the root folder of the project you want to add the external repository to and select TortoiseSVN –> Properties. ...
3. You will now see the subversion properties dialog.
4. Click the New.. button.
5. Add svn:external

For a complete howto, check [Howto](https://justinram.wordpress.com/2009/06/04/howto-add-svnexternals-in-windows-using-tortoisesvn/)